# Can't answer incoming Skype calls with my own launcher in Android

Tags: android, skype

I'm coding my own launcher on Android and when I receive a Skype call using this launcher I see the window of the incoming call but I can't answer the call... I can't do nothing after, it's blocking all.
With the default and other launchers Skype is working so the problem come from my launcher. But where ? Do I need a special permission ? Change something in the manifest ?

This is the permissions and the supports-screen of my Manifest :

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

This is my MainActivity in the Manifest :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 28 and I'm using a Samsung tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the Skype app, no from my app. I contacted them and they confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

As seen from comments, it seems not the case, but if it is a permission related problem, here's a sample from official repo. Skype is a phone app, so phone and contacts related permissions are needed I think.

From [OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/blob/master/HealthcareApp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:node="replace" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: No sorry it's not working at all... It seem the problem come from the Skype app.